# I am making a music player for android OS . However i am facing this

Tags: android

I have used a list view to display all the songs on the external card . When the user selects a particular song ,that song gets highlighted .[image]

This works fine but if i select another song from the same visible screen as the previously highlighted song then two songs get highlighted . If i again click then three songs get highlighted . If i scroll the screen and come back the listview refreshes itself and the only playing song is highlighted .[image]

Please help.
The code for my adapter

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter ;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class songcursoradapter extends CursorAdapter {
  public songcursoradapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
      super(context, cursor, 0);
  }

  // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it, 
  // you don't bind any data to the view at this point. 
  @Override
  public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.songs, parent, false);
  }

  // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
  // such as setting the text on a TextView. 
  @Override
  public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
      // Find fields to populate in inflated template
      TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
      TextView tvPriority = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_titl);
      // Extract properties from cursor
      String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
      String priority = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));


      // Populate fields with extracted properties
      tvBody.setText(body);
          //if song returned by cursor is the current song playing change color
          if(body==nowplaying.musicSrv.getTitle)                                       //musicSrv plays songs
             tvBody.setTextcolor(MainActivity.color)                                      //color is defined in MainActivity and is static
      tvPriority.setText(priority);
  }


}
```

Comment: Please share your code and release previous music player threads on click of listview other items.

Comment: seems that you have messed up in getView(), post your adapter code

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reset color if its not playing i.e. add else part

```
if(body==nowplaying.musicSrv.getTitle)    //musicSrv plays songs
   tvBody.setTextcolor(MainActivity.color);
else{
   tvBody.setTextcolor(MainActivity.default_color);
}
```

Comment: It does not work . A cursor adapter populates only those views which are visible .If I select one song ,it changes color . But if i select another song the previous selected song also retains its color . But i want the previous selected song to lose its color once I select  a new song . The previous selected song updates its color only when i scroll the screen up and bring it down or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

did you add these in your adapter :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return YourArrayList.size();
}
```

Also make your listView ChoiceMode is singleChoice.

xml code :

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

Comment: I am using a cursordapter and it is working properly

Comment: It should work, send your activity code through which you set adapter.